# i m using META BOX plugin and i created check box but unable to fetch value of check box

Tags: wordpress, plugins

```
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'your_prefix_meta_boxes' );
function your_prefix_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'title'      => __( 'Custom theme 2 Metabox ', 'textdomain' ),
        'post_types' => array('page'),
        'fields'     => array(
            array(
                'id'   => 'htitle',
                'name' => __( 'Home Page Title ', 'textdomain' ),
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
            array(
                'id'      => 'titlecss',
                'name'    => __( 'Title CSS', 'textdomain' ),
                'type'    => 'checkbox',
                'desc' => __( 'CSS For "WELCOME TO"', 'your-prefix' ),
                ), 
            array(
                'id'      => 'titlecss2',
                'name'    => __( 'Title CSS2', 'textdomain' ),
                'type'    => 'checkbox',
                'desc' => __( 'CSS For "Company name"', 'your-prefix' ),
                ),               
        ),
    );
    return $meta_boxes;
}
```

help to get checkbox value i got value of text box like this

```
<?php echo rwmb_meta( 'htitle' ); ?>
```

but i m not able to fetch value of checkbox please help

Comment: What do you mean by "i m not able to fetch value of checkbox" ? What happens ?

Comment: Ok, so please delete question, or answer it yourself... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo rwmb_meta( 'titlecss' ); ?
```

i got it by using id of checkbox